# how to save files in flutter on android version before 11 using light_compressor

Tags: android, flutter, dart, filesystems, file-saver

So I am trying to compress a video and display it but the code does not run

```dart
                        final dynamic compressedVid =
                            await _lightCompressor.compressVideo(
                                path: vid.path,
                                isMinBitrateCheckEnabled: false,
                                videoQuality: VideoQuality.very_low,
                                android: AndroidConfig(
                                    isSharedStorage: true, saveAt: SaveAt.Movies),
                                ios: IOSConfig(saveInGallery: true),
                                video: Video(videoName: "test-compressed.mp4"));
```

The above code work fine for android versions above 10. The issue comes when testing on android 10 or below. How can I make sure that the file is saved on other android versions as well?